# C# characters cannot be counted correctly (algorithm)

Tags: c#, algorithm

When I am trying to solve an ACSL algorithm question today, I encountered the following question:

> INPUT: There will be three integers representing the number of values to be found, the base to be used between 2 and 9 inclusive, and the starting value in the base given that will be no more than 16 digits.
> OUTPUT: For each set of 3 input values, output a base 10 number representing the number of
> times the largest digit in the inputted base occurs in the sequence of numbers generated.

> EXAMPLE: If n=15, b=8, and s=2, the numbers generated are 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20. The largest possible digit in base 8 is 7 which occurs 2 times.

I followed the instruction and this is the Minimum Reproducible Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TheFunc(25,5,324));
        // it should be 24, but it outputs 10
    }
    public static int TheFunc(int n, int b, int s)
    {
        List<string> num = new List<string>();
        string temp = "";
        int SumCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            num.Add(ChangeBaseEX(s + i, b));
        }

        foreach (var single in num)
        {
            temp += single;
        }

        SumCount = temp.Length - temp.Replace((b - 1).ToString(), "").Length;

        return SumCount;

    }
    public static string ChangeBaseEX(int num, int changeto)
    {
        string TheNumber = "";
        int RestNumber = 0;
        while (num > 0)
        {
            RestNumber = num % changeto;
            TheNumber = RestNumber.ToString() + TheNumber;
            num = num / changeto; //num/=changeto
        }
        return TheNumber;
    }
```

When I type `15, 8, 2`, it can show the result correctly, which is 2. However, when I type `25, 5, 324`, it outputs 10, which is incorrect(the correct output should be 24).

## what I tried:

**1:**
I tried to determine if my `ChangeBaseEX` function is correct:

```
        Console.WriteLine(ChangeBaseEX(20, 8));
        Console.WriteLine(ChangeBaseEX(4000, 6));
        Console.WriteLine(ChangeBaseEX(22, 2));
        //24
        //30304
        //10110
```

According to [Online base conversion tool](https://www.sojson.com/hexconvert.html), my base conversion is correct.

**2:**
I tried to print every value to determine if there are anything wrong with my counting, but it seemed that it is correct:

```
            //Console.WriteLine(s + i);
            //Console.WriteLine(ChangeBaseEX(s + i, b));
            //Console.WriteLine("=======");
```

**3:**
I tried to write the same code in many different ways. For example, I tried to change `SumCount = temp.Length - temp.Replace((b - 1).ToString(), "").Length;` into many other ways such as `single.Length - single.Replace((b - 1).ToString(), "").Length;`.

**4:**
I tried to use single step debugging, but I found nothing wrong.

## What I want:

I debugged every suspicious step and I found nothing wrong. In that case, I want to know which step I get wrong to let it count incorrectly.

Comment: Your `s + i` is wrong as s is the starting number *in the base given*. Also, it can be up to 16 digits long - too much for an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the fact that the third number is expressed in the indicated base. So `324` in base 5 is actually the decimal value `89`.

You'll need to pass the value in as a string, convert it from Base-N to an integer value, then use that as the starting point of your number sequence.

For instance:

```
static int CountMaxDigitsInSequence(int count, int baseNumber, string startValue)
{
    if (baseNumber < 2 || baseNumber > 9)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Invalid base number: {baseNumber}");
    if (startValue.Length > 16)
        throw new ArgumentException($"Start value too long: \"{startValue}\"");
    
    // Convert the Base-N string to a starting value
    int start = FromBaseN(startValue, baseNumber);
    
    // Get digit to search for
    char searchDigit = (char)('0' + baseNumber - 1);
    // Or: (baseNumber - 1).ToString()[0];
    
    // Counter
    int result = 0;
    
    // loop through the desired value list 
    for (int i = 0, value = start; i < count; i++, value++)
    {
        // Convert current value to string in Base-N
        string text = ToBaseN(value, baseNumber);
        // Count instances of our search digit
        foreach (var c in text)
        {
            if (c == searchDigit)
                result++;
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

// Convert a number in Base-N to an integer
// Where:
//  2 <= baseNumber <= 9
static int FromBaseN(string value, int baseNumber)
{
    if (baseNumber < 2 || baseNumber > 9)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Invalid base number: {baseNumber}");
    int result = 0;
    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        int digit = (int)(c - '0');
        if (digit < 0 || digit >= baseNumber)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid digit '{c}' in value \"{value}\".");
        result = result * baseNumber + digit;
    }
    return result;
}

// Convert an integer to a string in a paticular base.
// Where:
//  value > 0
//  2 <= baseNumber <= 9
static string ToBaseN(int value, int baseNumber)
{
    if (baseNumber < 2 || baseNumber > 9)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Invalid base number: {baseNumber}");
    if (value < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid value: {value}");
    string result = string.Empty;
    while (value > 0)
    {
        int digit = value % baseNumber;
        value /= baseNumber;
        // This is a little dirty, but it works.
        result = digit.ToString() + result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

And just for fun, here's a stripped-down `ToBaseN()` implementation using `Span<char>` to reduce the number of allocations.

```
static string ToBaseN(int value, int baseNumber)
{
    Span<char> buffer = stackalloc char[17];
    int index = 1;
    while (value > 0)
    {
        buffer[^(index++)] = (char)('0' + value % baseNumber);
        value /= baseNumber;
    }
    return new string(buffer[^(index)..]);
}
```